# I want to pass an object type Stack and a String to another Method in the same Class, but it gives me an error.

Tags: java, object

I don't know what kind of error it is, this is my code:

```
public static void Entrada() {
    Stack operStack;
    String oper = Teclado.cadena("¿Qué operación desea realizar?");
    oper = oper.replaceAll(" ", "");
    operStack=new Stack(oper.length());
    ConversionStrToArr(String oper, Stack operStack); //Here appears the error message
}

public static void ConversionStrToArr(String oper, Stack operStack){

    for(int i=1;i<=oper.length();i++)
        operStack.Push(oper.charAt(i));        
}
```

Comment: `for(int i=1;i<=oper.length();i++)` should be `for(int i=0;i<oper.length();i++)`. Also `ConversionStrToArr(String oper, Stack operStack);` should be `ConversionStrToArr(oper, operStack);`

Comment: Do we guess the error or...?

Comment: You need to remove the `String` and `Stack` from the parameters in your method call. You should be able to see the problem from there.

Comment: Did you read what the error said?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call in this way

```
ConversionStrToArr(oper, operStack);
```

When you call a method then you just pass the value. You don't need to define the type of values at the time of method call.

Note : follow the Java naming conventions.

Comment: And just for the completeness of the "follow the Java naming conventions", for anyone having a hard time finding good sources (as the oracle links to the conventions seems broken):
http://www.scribd.com/doc/15884743/Java-Coding-Style-by-Achut-Reddy
or
http://www.ambysoft.com/downloads/javaCodingStandards.pdf

Comment: **Google** will definitely help in it. Thanks a lot. It's very helpful.